# How to get top 3 users according to rating

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using php with mysql and i want to get top 3 user whose rating is high
I have following table

Table name - rating

```
id      user_id     rating  
1       4           3
2       4           5
3       5           3
4       6           4
5       5           2
```

Now i want to get data according to ratings ( top rating users should be above with limit 3 users)
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM rating ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: No please see my table carefully, i want rating after calculating ( i am talking about average rating)

Comment: @JigarBakshi just do: `select user_id from rating group by user_id order by avg(rating) DESC LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 1):

You should group by user_id, then calculate the rating average and finally sort and limit acordingly to your needs:

```
SELECT user_id, AVG(rating) as 'Average Rating' 
FROM rating 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY 'Average Rating' DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```